# Ways to reduce packets per second (Bundle VPN Packets?)

Tags: iptables, vpn

I have an ISP that blocks me when I do more than `10 pps` on any port. Only exception: ports `80` and `443` where I am allowed `100 pps`.
To avoid being blocked I can use a VPN on port `80` or `443` which then leaves me with a `100 pps` overall limit. That isn't perfect either.

What can I do to reduce my packets per second load?

I thought there might be a vpn software that could bundle small packets into bigger ones, but have not found anything. That would create some lag but I think that is better than being blocked.

Other suggestions are also welcome. Maybe some `iptables` magic or something, but just blocking everthing over `100 pps` just makes the connection unusable.

For clarification: I have Linux machines on both ends.

Comment: If you are limited based on destination port, you can use different ports at the same time.

Comment: Is that possible with something like `OpenVPN`? To have one VPN connection that is split over multiple ports?

Comment: Wow, that is one spectacularly bad ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use **compression** with the provider of your VPN. This will potentially reduce the number of packets used for communication.

Also, make sure that you tweak the VPN settings to **use the maximum packet size without fragmentation**. So you can put as much compressed packets into as little packets on port 80.

Comment: Does compression like `lzo` for `OpenVPN` automatically merge/bundle/combine packets?

Comment: It should compress the stream sent via the VPN link.

Comment: As far as I have read, normal VPN implementations just wrap and optionally compress / encrypt the packets. That would not reduce the pps which is the limit on my connection